# Select option in drop down list based on text box input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of drop down lists that according to my selection, and some necessary calculations I would like to be able to automatically select the value o yet another drop down lists. The way i had it configured before, using a text box instead of a drop down it worked, but the requirements of my project needed me to switch to a drop down list.

This is the way i had when using a text box:

```
var minusOne =        ["19","23","201","202","205","206","215","216","217","224","225","226","228","238","237","245","246","247","248","249","250","251","73","207","208","209","210","211","212","213","214","203","227","309","1302","134","135","136","142","762"];
var plusOne =["37"];
$("select[title='Crop Year']").change(function() {
var year = Number($(this).val());
var crop = $("select[title='Crop'] option:selected").text().split(' -');
var index = $.inArray(crop[0],minusOne),
indexII = $.inArray(crop[0],plusOne);
//TEXT BOX
index >= 0 ? $("input[title='RY']").val(year-1) : indexII >= 0 ?      $("input[title='RY']").val(year+1) : $("input[title='RY']").val(year);});
```

Now I would like to change the part below //Text Box to a drop down list. This is what I've tried without luck so far:

```
........
//DROP DOWN - Option I  
if (index >= 0){$('select[title="RYTest"]').find(year-1).attr('selected','selected');}
else if (indexII >= 0)  {$('select[title="RYTest"]').find(year+1).attr('selected','selected');}
else {$('select[title="RYTest"]').find(year).attr('selected','selected');}});

//DROP DOWN - Option II

if (index >= 0) {$('#LookupID  option[text="' + year-1 + '"]').prop('selected',true);}
else if (indexII >= 0){$('#LookupID option[text="' + year+1 + '"]').prop('selected',true);}
else {$('#LookupID option[text="' + year + '"]').prop('selected',true);}});
```

I would really appreciate any help here. I just want to let you know that i can't add or remove options from this list (no .prepend($(''), etc, etc). This dropdown lst get it info from a SharePoint list. Please also notice that #LookupID and select[title="RYTest"] are the same element.

Thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it.

```
$("select[title='RYTest'] option:contains(" + $("input[title='RY']").val() + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```